# shiny with portable R?

Tags: r, shiny

For building some web services with R, I normally use [RApache](http://rapache.net/) but I want to have a look at Shiny to see what it can do. 
Problem is that for this situation where I am envisioning it to use, I do not have a server available where I can run R & shiny, nor can I transfer data to another machine where it runs. I only have a desktop and I want to show the Shiny application to other users without having them to install R on their desktops and without bothering IT about that installation.

Hence my question. Is it possible that I install R portable - http://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/files/R-Portable/ on a shared drive which is shared with colleagues and that the Shiny application can interact with the portable R version.
If this is possible, has someone tried it out and is willing to share some of his code to prove that it works?

Comment: I think this more a question for superuser than stack exchange as its software installation, not coding

Comment: I'm not interested about the software installation. That I know how to do. I'm just interested in how Shiny knows which R to communicate with.

Comment: I do this frequently at work. I installed R + libraries on the file server and share the map with the ui.r en server.R files via the file server as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work fine, assuming you can get your R-Portable setup to have a portable package library. Shiny doesn't launch R, you run R and then from there load and launch your Shiny app (using `shiny::runApp()`), and then the browser and R process communicate using TCP.

If your apps don't need to be private you could also apply for an account on RStudio's own Shiny hosting. It's free while in beta. https://rstudio.wufoo.com/forms/shiny-server-beta-program/

Comment: Great. Thanks for the confirmation. I'll give the R-portable setup a try.

Comment: shiny runs and listens by default on port 8100, but I can't see if its only on localhost or on all interfaces. Assuming it *can* listen on external interfaces then you just need to run it and give the URL to anyone you want to see your app. Ports other than port 80 might be a problem with people's firewalls though, and port 80 requires root privileges (on linux at least) so you'll be running R as root...

Comment: Hmm, I tried on R-portable with library(shiny); runExample("01_hello"); but I'm getting: "Error in as.environment(x) : invalid object for 'as.environment'", caused by cacheContext <- CacheContext$new(). Any clues on what is causing this error? Running it with the non-portable R works however... so what is the difference between the 2?

Answer (score 2):

OS: Windows 7 - 64 bit

Follow the steps as explained in the link below, except create a single batch file to run the shiny app, because the suggestion to start a web browser in that web link does not work (web browser opens up without the app content), at least for me.

This batch script finds an **UNUSED UNPRIVILEGED PORT** and uses it to open a local web application ([Portable R Shiny App](http://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/)) using portable google chrome web browser from a USB Flash drive. In the above weblink, the author's suggestion to create separate runShinyApp.R and run.bat is condensed to a single batch file as given below.

```
@echo off
    title 'My Shiny APP'

    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    for /l %%X in (1025,1,65535) do (   
        netstat -o -n -a | findstr :%%X 
        if !ERRORLEVEL! neq 0 ( 
            set avail_port=%%X
            goto eof
        ) 
    )

    :eof
    SET ROPTS=--no-save --no-environ --no-init-file --no-restore --no-Rconsole

    start "" ".\GoogleChromePortable\App/Chrome-bin/chrome.exe" "http://localhost:!avail_port!/"

    R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\Rscript.exe %ROPTS% -e "require(methods); shiny::runApp('./shiny', launch.browser = FALSE, port = !avail_port!)" 1> ShinyAppOut.log 2> ShinyAppMsg.log
```